# Installing two copies of the same site with same db and prefix for a test - is this ok

Tags: php

Before i start i know what your going to say no no no no no never install Joomla sites with the same prefix or on the same db but hear me out.

Its the same website essentially one installed in route and one in route/dir
Essentially the route website file structure has somehow become corrupt.

So as a test i have installed a rolled back version in a sub directory. I simply want to login and check the error has gone and then migrate the files to live.

Im not updating any articles or anything as the error was with the login. However i am worried if i create a session by logging in it might mess things up

Is this ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can safely do this in this scenario. Be sure to backup your database first - just as extra safety - and in the new site's configuration.php change the paths for cache and logs. This is not mandatory, but is recommended if you don't really want to touch anything in the live site - not even these two directories.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I didn't need to do this in the end and managed to resolve the issue I was having. Much appreciated.